# HTML5 video open file error fallback

Tags: html, html5-video, fallback

I have a similar question as [HTML5 video, fallback to flash if no .ogv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763042/html5-video-fallback-to-flash-if-no-ogv-file)

But my question is I want to fallback to flash if browser CAN'T OPEN .ogv file (not DOESN'T SUPPORT ogv). Suppose my html already has preset fallback codes below source elements, can I instruct browsers continue executing these preset fallback codes if all sources are failed to open (i.e. no source network state)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sniff whether browser supports or does not support OGV beforehand before playing it:

http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#video-formats

Comment: But if your problem is network is b0rked then this does not help much :( However, this list of MediaElement events might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Media_events

Comment: Actually, we are moving to html5 and decide we'll use mp4 and ogv in the future but it's not possible to reconvert all old flv videos (they are too many). When users happen to play an old video on our site, the broswer wouldn't find mp4 and ogv files (they won't exist as you see) and I wish broswers continue to execute followed fallback codes. So it's neither NOT-SUPPORT nor NETWORK-BROKEN situations.

Comment: You can fix this on the server side, as the server knows whether the video is available or not.

Comment: The server is Adobe FMIS and we are not devoting any efforts for those old flv. I just wish when browsers interprets 2 source elements (mp4 and ogv) and see no source is available, it will continue executing those fallback codes after these 2 source elements of video tag. One possible way I know so far is catching events and check NO_SOURCE network state of the video tag. However, I wish there's a more direct and simpler way.