# html5-video-tag supported, but mime-type not - give an alternative link

Tags: html5-video, mime-types

We use the html5-video-tag.
Sometimes we get only one video-source (.mp4).

For browsers which does not support the html5-video - all is OK, there the fall-back method works:

```
<video>
    <object with flash></object>
</video>
```

Problem occurs if only a .mp4 is provided. The Firefox only displays "Kein Video mit unterstützem Format und Mime-Type gefunden". Yes Firefox cannot display .mp4 videos.

What can I do to force the Firefox (or any browser which does not support the mime-type) to show the alternative object-flash-section?

Exists an attribute for the html5-video-tag to force pass-through on error?
Or can I catch an Event "onerror" ...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to detecter wether a file type is supported :

```
(function (video) {
    if (!video.canPlayType || !video.canPlayType('video/mp4')) {
        // Flash fallback
    }
}(document.createElement('video')));
```

As said in [HTML5 video, fallback to flash if no .ogv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763042/html5-video-fallback-to-flash-if-no-ogv-file)